# radiobuttons on different tabcontrol stay selected

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button, tabcontrol

Please read de question as it´s not a duplicate. 
I have a winforms app i C# witch has a tabcontrol with 3 tabs. 
Each tab has 4 radiobuttons. 
If i run the app, the radio buttons work fine within the same tab, but when i select another tab the selection remains in the first tab.
I tried to clear all checked radiobuttons when changing tabs but for some reason it does not work.
The code is use is:

```
private void UncheckLayouts(TabPage activePage)
{
    foreach (Control control in tabControl1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is RadioButton)
        {
            RadioButton rb = control as RadioButton;
            rb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}

private void radioButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UncheckLayouts(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}

private void radioButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UncheckLayouts(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
...
```

I tried like this too:

```
private void tabControl1_Deselecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
    foreach (var ctrl in e.TabPage.Controls) {
         if (ctrl is RadioButton) {
             RadioButton tb = ctrl as RadioButton;
             rb.Checked = false;
         }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
new code.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    tabControl1.Selected += TabControl1_Selected;
}
private void TabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in e.TabPage.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is RadioButton)
        {
            RadioButton tb = ctrl as RadioButton;
            tb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But no solution works.
All radiobuttons were added to each tab with the designer.

Can anyone help please.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code，I tested that it was working fine

```
private void InitializeComponent(){
           ........
 tabControl1.Selected += TabControl1_Selected;
}



private void TabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in e.TabPage.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is RadioButton)
        {
            RadioButton tb = ctrl as RadioButton;
            tb.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the help. 
i tried your code but get an error in line  `tabControl1.Selected += TabControl1_Selected;` `No overload for 'TabControl1_Selected' matches delegate 'TabControlEventHandler' `

Comment: I updated my post with your solution, is it ok?
I still get an error on `tabControl1.Selected += TabControl1_Selected;`

Comment: i`m sorry ,I copied the wrong code，i have fixed my code